# How to create a node with multiple node in neo4j using java api

Tags: java, neo4j

I am learning basics of neo4j and trying to create node with multiple labels but not able to do so.

Question: How to create a neo4j node using java api. I am only able to add a single label to node at a time.

Using neo4j 3.4.6

Note: I don not want to use cypher, but only java api

```java
/* This will create a node with label MY_LABEL */
Node tnode = db.createNode(Label.label("MY_LABEL"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The `GraphDatabaseService.createNode(Label... labels)` method allows you to use multiple `Label` objects as its parameter. Therefore, you should simply call the method like `db.createNode(Label.label("MY_LABEL"), Label.label("MY_LABEL_1"), Label.label("MY_LABEL_2"), Label.label("MY_LABEL_3"));`